# Do we need to purchase Doka Image Editor first and then we are able to use it with image upload modules like react-dropzone and fileponed?

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm using [fileponed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-filepond) module in one of my project for upload image functionality and it provides integration of Image Editor with [Doka Pulgin](https://pqina.nl/doka). I've successfully implemented simple upload functionality with [fileponed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-filepond) in reactJs but didn't find any opensource module for [doka](https://pqina.nl/doka). I need to purchase [it](https://pqina.nl/doka) if I want it's distribution folder?

Comment: Hi, author of FilePond and Doka Image Editor here. Doka is a commercial product and you'll have to purchase a license to access the source files.

Comment: @Rik Thank you. We have purchased it

Comment: @Rik Will love to see the image editor of filepond itself. Any thought on that?

Comment: @ShubhamDubey I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Rik I was suggesting making an image editor of filepond itself just like Doka. I know it's a lot. Was curious if there is any chance for that in the future.

Comment: @ShubhamDubey Doka Image Editor integrates seamlessly with FilePond. I don’t see the need to put and image editor inside FilePond as FilePond is about file uploading not editing.